# Storing Objects in LocalStorage with VUE.js

Tags: javascript

I need to store an Object called Projects that contains Teams and each Team contains users, all that without tables or other sql stuff, all in localstorage, and after I need to CRUD them and all that stuff. Any Ideas?

```js
project = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('projects'));
console.log(project);
project.push(this.projectname);    
localStorage.setItem("projects",JSON.stringify(project));
```

Comment: Looks like you're doing it already. What's your question?

Comment: You are already storing projects object in localstorage, Can you elaborate on where you need help exactly?

Comment: I came from Java, Objects have ojects inside them, I don't know how I save stuff inside this JSON

Comment: Does project need to be an array?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use an array of objects, something like below :

```
var user1 = {"name":"user1"}; //Object1
var user2 = {"name":"user2"}; //Object2
var team = []; //array of objects
team.push(user1);
team.push(user2);
var projects = [];
projects.push(team);
console.log(projects); //store this into localstorage
```

Comment: Now the only thing left is to know how I get the same object and save it after editing

Comment: projects[0] will give you the first team, projects[0][0] will give you the first user.

Comment: so we can say that "project" only has one project

Comment: adding the array to local storage will store the items in the array as string representations of the objects, not the objects themselves.  (e.g. "[object Object],[object Object]" )